# Tomcat error for missing APR library, even though it's installed

Tags: ssl, tomcat, apr

I'm running Tomcat 8.0.49, and set up an SSL connector.  This is a connector that works in my other Tomcat instances, which are at version 7.x.  Connecting to the instance via a web browser hangs, and it seems it's because the SSL Connector isn't starting properly.  This seems because it can't find the APR library, which I think I've installed.  Any thoughts on why?  Please see below.

This is what I get in catalina.out:

```
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.357 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

This is even though I have the following RPMs installed (seems like I may only need apr and apr-devel):

```
$ sudo rpm -qa apr openssl-devel apr-util apr-devel apr
openssl-devel-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64
apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64
apr-1.4.8-5.el7.x86_64
apr-devel-1.4.8-5.el7.x86_64
```

This is what I see for apr:

```
$ sudo find / -name '*apr*'
..
/usr/bin/apr-1-config
..
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libsaproc.so
/usr/lib64/apr-1
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/apr_rules.mk
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/apr-1.pc
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.so
/usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0
/usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.la
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0.4.8
/usr/lib64/apr-util-1
```

This is the connector from server.xml:

```
<Connector SSLCertificateFile="path-of-mycertfile-here.crt" SSLCertificateKeyFile="path-of-my-keyfile-here.key" SSLCipherSuite="HIGH:MEDIUM:!RC4:!DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:!ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA:!3DES:!aNULL:!eNULL" SSLEnabled="true" SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2" URIEncoding="UTF-8" clientAuth="false" maxThreads="150" port="9443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true"/>
```

This is the environment information, also from catalina.out:

```
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.349 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.352 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 19 2018 20:21:23 UTC
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.x
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_262-b10
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.49
02-Oct-2020 13:53:52.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.49
```

Comment: Did you install the `tomcat-native` package?

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason, I couldn't find the package before, but I installed it now, and it worked. It sets up the SSL connector properly. I'm guessing apr, apr-util, openssl-devel and apr-devel should not be needed, or that yum should address it as a dependency.